# Are there any kernels which can upgrade without reboot?

Tags: kernel, software-rec

(excluding toy, academic-only, and unmaintained)

My use-case is getting nontechnical people to have servers deployed for them, and for neither me nor them to worry about [attended] maintenance and security. Maximum of 3 binaries deployed, each written in C or C++. Need some of the TCP/IP stack. Open to BSD, illumos, Linux &etc.

Thanks

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. But there are offers for live patching Linux kernels since many years. Most security problems are not the kernel though but applications, which means just having live patching kernels does not really solve the maintenance problem.

Answer (score 0):

> and for neither me nor them to worry about [attended] maintenance and security.

Yes they exist - but definitely not for low maintenance consumer installations. Most open-source distributions have automatic patching (with reboots for certain components). And avoiding rebooting is a bad strategy for providing high-availability even if such capability were commonplace.

Comment: Thanks yeah I've been kind of familiar with livepatch for years, but it still sometimes requires reboots. I confirmed the other day on `comp.os.linux.misc`. HA isn't really needed, I suppose if no one recommends a better solution I'll end up exposing some authenticated "click this button to reboot server for upgrade" to the nontechnical user.